# How to set items of a sparse matrix given the row and column indices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have a list of lists where each sub list includes the column indices of the successive rows to be set into 1.

```
indices = [[1,43,243],[2,34,276],...]
```

My purpose is to set values of scipy sparse matrix conforming to given indices.

For example:

for the first row 1,43,243 the columns need to be set into 1
for the second row 2,34,276 the columns need to be set into 1

if it is a silly question sorry for that. I am just a beginner who got the transition from Matlab to scipy.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the `sparse` matrix types will work.  From the `sparse.csr_matrix` documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

```
>>> row = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
>>> col = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
>>> data = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) ).todense()
matrix([[1, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
```

`coo_matrix` also takes this `(data,(row,col))` input

Matlab provides a similar means of creating a sparse matrix, complete with the business about adding duplicate entries (see note at base of the `coo_matrix` documentation).

I think you want to construct

```
row = array([0,0,0, 1,1,1,2,2,2,....])
col = array([1,43,243, 2,34,276,,...])  
# col = col-1 # to change to 0 based indexing?
data = array([1,1,1,...])
```

For example:

```
np.array(indices).ravel()
# array([  1,  43, 243,   2,  34, 276])
np.arange(2).repeat(3)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
np.ones(6)
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```